# DNS records added based on info provided by Heroku, but URL still not resolving correctly

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, heroku

Awhile ago I registered the domain name www.testapp.id with my registrar (Namecheap).  The application I want it to point to is a Rails app hosted on Heroku. I'm following the instructions on Heroku's site [here](https://help.heroku.com/VKRNVVF5/what-is-the-correct-dns-cname-target-for-my-custom-domains), specifically:

> You can check the correct CNAME target for Custom Domains by running the Heroku CLI command: heroku domains -a your_app_name.
>
> - Custom Domains created before herokudns.com was available will
>     display your_app_name.herokuapp.com as the DNS CNAME target. Custom
> - Domains recently created will display
>     your_custom_domain.herokudns.com as the DNS CNAME target.
>
> You should setup your DNS CNAME targets based on these settings, although using your_app_name.herokuapp.com will work for both OLD and NEW Custom Domains. If the .herokudns.com is available for the Custom Domain, then you should use this as it will make transitioning to Heroku SSL easier in the future.

I currently have only the following URL Redirect Record and CNAME record set up on Namecheap:

[image: screenshot of Namecheap records configuration]

On the Heroku side, when I run `heroku domains`, I see the following output:

```
[ hello-world ] $  heroku domains
=== hidden-beach-71618 Heroku Domain
hidden-beach-71618.herokuapp.com

=== hidden-beach-71618 Custom Domains
Domain Name  DNS Record Type  DNS Target
───────────  ───────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
testapp.id   ALIAS or ANAME   concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com
```

Navigating to the `hidden-beach` URL in my browser results in a successful display of the app, however navigating to `http://www.testapp.id` does not.  I've waited about 30 min before re-trying, and I'd expect that to be enough time for the results to propagate.

Executing `dig www.testapp.id` in my CLI results in the following:

```
[ hello-world ] $  dig www.testapp.id

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.testapp.id
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57445
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 9, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 17

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.testapp.id.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.testapp.id.     1703    IN  CNAME   concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com.
concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com. 59 IN A 52.207.111.186
concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com. 59 IN A 52.22.236.254
concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com. 59 IN A 34.199.255.1
concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com. 59 IN A 52.45.248.161
concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com. 59 IN A 34.226.180.131
concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com. 59 IN A 54.236.200.27
concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com. 59 IN A 34.206.9.96
concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com. 59 IN A 52.203.66.95

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            155416  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            155416  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.gtld-servers.net. 5594    IN  A   192.5.6.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 8284    IN  A   192.33.14.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 6036    IN  AAAA    2001:503:231d::2:30
c.gtld-servers.net. 155416  IN  AAAA    2001:503:83eb::30
d.gtld-servers.net. 155416  IN  AAAA    2001:500:856e::30
e.gtld-servers.net. 15649   IN  A   192.12.94.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 15509   IN  AAAA    2001:502:1ca1::30
f.gtld-servers.net. 14627   IN  A   192.35.51.30
f.gtld-servers.net. 11150   IN  AAAA    2001:503:d414::30
g.gtld-servers.net. 147526  IN  A   192.42.93.30
h.gtld-servers.net. 6533    IN  A   192.54.112.30
i.gtld-servers.net. 155416  IN  AAAA    2001:503:39c1::30
j.gtld-servers.net. 147526  IN  A   192.48.79.30
k.gtld-servers.net. 155416  IN  A   192.52.178.30
l.gtld-servers.net. 147526  IN  AAAA    2001:500:d937::30
m.gtld-servers.net. 9832    IN  AAAA    2001:501:b1f9::30

;; Query time: 57 msec
;; SERVER: 10.100.8.11#53(10.100.8.11)
;; WHEN: Wed May 08 16:40:51 PDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 819
```

I see in the answer section that my URL is resolving to Heroku's DNS URL, which is what I'd expect, given the instructions from Heroku.

Also, when I tail the server logs (`heroku logs -t` from my local project repo), I see the logs but I don't see any activity when I refresh my browser, so I know the server isn't receiving the request.

In addition to creating a CNAME record with the herokudns.com domain I was given, I also tried creating an NS record and (unsuccessfully) creating an A record (even though I'm aware that A records only accept IPs).

My question is- what am I overlooking?  Did I fail to create the right type of record, or is it something else I'm not aware of?

Comment: `www.testapp.id` resolves to a CNAME of `hidden-beach-71618.herokuapp.com` for me, not the `concentric-wildfowl-rsf834gfj5eft9k4mqvpvjkp.herokudns.com` one. Not just me, either. https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/www.testapp.id I see a `*.testapp.id` record, but do you *also* have a `www` one?

Comment: Apologies, I was trying additional workarounds and forgot to change back to the `concentric-wildfowl` address.  Just fixed that, should propagate momentarily.

Comment: I do not currently have any DNS record in place for `www`.

Comment: Your other problem is that your `heroku domains` shows that `concentric-wildfowl` custom domain is for `testapp.id`, not `www.testapp.id`. You need to add the www to your app's `heroku domains`, not the non-www (which is being handled by Namecheap's redirect instead of Heroku). (This will also give you a *different* CNAME to use...)